# Make one foreach iteration instead of 4 in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am learning PowerShell and trying to figure out if I can just create one loop to get the following output.

```
$array = "Rick","John","James","Rocky","Smith", "Rob", "Joab","Riah","Rio"

foreach($nameMatch in $array){
if($nameMatch -like 'Ri*'){
write-Host "here is name starts with Ri:" $nameMatch
}
}

foreach($nameMatch in $array){
if($nameMatch -like 'Ro*'){
write-Host "here is name starts with Ro:" $nameMatch
}
}
foreach($nameMatch in $array){
if($nameMatch -like 'Jo*'){
write-Host "here is name starts with Jo:" $nameMatch
}
}
foreach($nameMatch in $array){
if($nameMatch -like 'Ja*'){
write-Host "here is name starts with Ja:" $nameMatch
}
}
```

output: here is name starts with Ri: Rick Riah Rio,
here is name starts with Ro: Rocky Rob,
here is name starts with Jo: John Joab,
here is name starts with Ja:James

Comment: If you want to write-host 4 different things with loops then yes you’ll need 4. If you just want to output all names that match any, then you could use one. Is it important to say “this name, this name, this name, etc”?

Comment: @DougMaurer will the list be in order if I remove the this name, this name? for example output to be: Rick Riah Rio Rocky Rob John Joab James. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this. You can get the output of the names without a loop with regex `-Match` with the '|' (or) regex operator

```
$array = "Rick","John","James","Rocky","Smith", "Rob", "Joab","Riah","Rio"

$array -match 'Ri|Ro|Jo|Ja'
```

Output

```
Rick
John
James
Rocky
Rob
Joab
Riah
Rio
```

You could parameterize the foreach loop

```
'Ri','Ro','Jo','Ja' | Foreach-Object {
    write-Host "here is name starts with $_ :"
    $array -like "$_*"
}
```

Output

```
here is name starts with Ri :
Rick
Riah
Rio
here is name starts with Ro :
Rocky
Rob
here is name starts with Jo :
John
Joab
here is name starts with Ja :
James
```

Or even use a switch statement

```
Switch -Regex ($array){
    'Ri' {$_}
    'Ro' {$_}
    'Jo' {$_}
    'Ja' {$_}
}
```

Output

```
Rick
John
James
Rocky
Rob
Joab
Riah
Rio
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create another array for the starts you want to match, you can have a single loop. Like this:

```
$array = "Rick","John","James","Rocky","Smith", "Rob", "Joab","Riah","Rio"
$toMatch = "Ri","Ro","Jo","Ja"

foreach ( $m in $toMatch )
{
    Write-Host "`nHere is names starts with $m :"
    $array | where { $_ -match "^$m" } | foreach { $_ }
}
```

If do not want to, or can have another loop, you will have to have one loop for each test:

```
$array = "Rick","John","James","Rocky","Smith", "Rob", "Joab","Riah","Rio"

Write-Host "`nHere is name starts with Ri:"
$array | where { $_ -match "^Ri" } | foreach { $_ }

Write-Host "`nHere is name starts with Ro:"
$array | where { $_ -match "^Ro" } | foreach { $_ }

Write-Host "`nHere is name starts with Jo:"
$array | where { $_ -match "^Jo" } | foreach { $_ }

Write-Host "`nHere is name starts with Ja:"
$array | where { $_ -match "^Ja" } | foreach { $_ }
```